# Interchange of Limits and Incorrect proof Monotone Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Two things came across my mind.

> **Question** 1: Suppose $f_n: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous for all $n$ and $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$, then
> $$\lim \int f_n = \int f$$

The standard proof is triangle inequality. $$\left | \int_{a}^{b} (f_n - f) \right | \leq \int_{a}^{b} | (f_n - f)| \leq \int_{a}^{b} \| (f_n - f)\|_\infty \to 0 $$

But I thought to myself why couldn't the last inequality be replaced by $\int_{a}^{b} |f_n - f| <  \int_{a}^{b}  \epsilon$ where by we may assume pointwise convergence instead. I know there are counterexamples to this statement, so there must be some mistake in this reasoning.

**Question 2:** Next is **Monotone Convergence theorem** (Lesbegue).

> If $(f_n)$ is increasing of nonnegative measurable functions then
>
> $$\lim \int f_n = \int f$$

Here we can in fact relax condition to point wise (a.e.) but an added condition that the sequence is monotone increasing (and nonegativity). Why isn't uniform convergence **alone** enough here? Sorry if this might be an amateur question.

(1) is meant for question 1, (2) is meant for question 2

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100242/discussion-on-question-by-hawk-interchange-limits-and-incorrect-proof-monoton-co).

Answer (score 2):

(1) if you only assume pointwise convergence the $\varepsilon$ is depending on $x$ therefore the integral $\int_a^b \varepsilon (x) dx $ can still produce problems. This could provide a problem also for every $x$ you need a different $n$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x) | < \varepsilon$. Since the $n$ is not fixed you can not do this.

(2) You should figure out if the lebesgueintegral and riemannintegral are equivalent. Else you just give up the uniform in uniform convergence for monotone. Wich is just a different statement. 
Uniform convergence should work if lebesgueintegral and riemannintegral are equivalent.

Comment: (1) I am guessing because in (1) that we need to keep changing $N(x,\epsilon)$ to ensure the inequality holds? But theoretically if we can magically control $N$ at each stage the inequality would work? 

(2) What do you mean equivalent here?

Comment: (1)Yes, If you could say there is a fixed N such that the inequality holds. But Thema you end up with Uniform convergence.

Comment: For (2) in your case the lebesgueintegral and riemannintegral give the same result since you are on a Compact Intervall. Therefore with uniform convergence you can swap the limes and integral.

Comment: (1) It isn't possible to say the "max(N)" that works right?

Comment: no since max(N) doesn't exist. You'd need uniform convergence for the existence of max(N). What I mean when I say max(N) doesn't exist it tends to be infinte.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for editing the question, but you didn't increase the number of steps in the proof. In my opinion, the crucial missing step that you didn't write down, as I tried to mention in my second comment above, is
$$ \int_a^b \|f_n - f \|_\infty = (b-a) \|f_n-f\|_{\infty} \to 0.$$
This uses two important properties:

1. $b-a<\infty$. Thus the issue when discussing integrals over e.g. unbounded intervals. In particular its not true that uniform convergence is enough to conclude that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n dx \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty f dx $, even if all integrals involved are finite. But nevermind; lets from now on talk about integrals on $[a,b]$.
2. $\|f_n - f\|_{\infty}=\sup_{y\in[a,b]} |f_n(y) -f(y)| $ is independent of $x$. This is the part you are glossing over. The fact that $|f_n(x) -f(x)|$ can decay at a rate that depends on the point spoils the whole proof.

> (1) As I said, I am not asking for a counter example, there is plenty in books. I just want to know why the last step might not be replaceable by the point wise inequality

It seems that you think that the use of a counterexample is only to give quick short proofs of why a result doesn't hold when you drop an assumption. In actuality (and I hope TheoretialEconomist has convinced you) a good counterexample should allow you to pinpoint exactly what step doesn't work in the proof, lets you create your own more elaborate counterexamples, and ideally leads to correct generalisations of the result.

Here's another example. Lets consider the function

$$ \tilde T:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R, \quad \tilde T(x) =\max(1-|2x-1|,0)$$ 
What an ugly definition, you might say. I chose this one because (a) your Question 1 asks for continuous functions. The max of continuous is continuous. (b) You seem to be confused in the comments without an explicit formula. But actually this is literally just the symmetric "tent" triangle of height 1, base 1, centered at $x=1/2$. (i.e. the graph is like $\_ \Lambda\_$ ). Its area is 1/2, by highschcool geometry. Or compute the integral, probably good to do once in your life.

Now consider the continuous functions (desmos graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dzlwhrwohj))
$$ T_n: [0,1] \to \mathbb R,\quad  T_n(x) := n \tilde T(n x)$$
In words: $T_n$ squishes the $x$ axis of $\tilde T$ by a multiplying factor of $1/n$ (hence $nx$), and then changes the height to be $n$ (hence the $n$ on the outside). Thus the area is still 1/2 for each $n$. Or compute the integral with a change of variables $y=nx$.

The punchline of this sequence is that $T_n(x) \to 0$ pointwise. Yes, every point, even for $x\ll 1$, and this is because when $n\gg 1$, the tip of the triangle will be to the left of $x$, and its downhill from then on. Thus we have $T_n$ and the pointwise limit $T\equiv 0$ are perfectly continuous functions, but the conclusion doesn't hold; $\frac12 = \int_0^1 T_n \not\to \int_0^1T = 0$.

The point is that the area has "escaped to vertical infinity near 0". (Indeed, $T_n \to 0$ uniformly on every interval $[\epsilon,1]$, $\epsilon > 0$.) In fact, escape to vertical infinity is precisely what uniform convergence prevents. This general phenomenon is what I would present to you as the answer to your query (1). Note that
$$ \|f\|_\infty < C$$
is a strongly visual statement, and it says: you can draw the horizontal lines $y=C$, $y=-C$, and the graph of $y=f(x)$ lies strictly between them. And it turns out that this is enough for the proof to work.

What else can we do? We can try to add assumptions to make pointwise convergence work. Observe in the above that a key problem is that points can keep going out to infinity. One way to prevent that is to assume
$$\text{for each } x\in[a,b], f_n(x) \text{ is decreasing in $n$ to }  f.$$
Then it turns out that we have the following theorem-

> If $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ converges pointwise to $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, $f_n,f$ are continuous and for each $x$, $f_n(x)$ decreases to $f$, then $\int_0^1 f_n = \int_0^1 f$.

The proof is nothing more than an application of Dini's Lemma, which gives the uniform convergence. Its not hard to turn this into a statement about increasing functions, which proves a "monotone convergence theorem" for continuous functions.

Or maybe you noticed that the derivative of the triangle gets large. If we prevented the derivative from getting huge, e.g. by asking that $f'_n\to f'$ uniformly. Can we get a result, for say $C^1([0,1])$ functions such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise? The answer is yes, and this is because
\begin{align} 
|f(x)-f_n(x)| 
&= \left|f(0)-f_n(0) + \int_0^x f'(y) - f'_n(y) dy\right| \\ &\le |f(0)-f_n(0)| + \int_0^1 |f'(y)-f'_n(y)| dy \\ 
&\le |f(0)-f_n(0)| + \|f'_n - f'\|_{\infty}, \end{align}
and this upper bound is independent of $x$. Curiously we only need to assume $f_n\to f$ at one point $(!)$

Anyways. On to the second point-

> (2) Just want to know why point wise increasing can't be replaced by uniform convergence as stated.

There are 2 reasons why I don't think one can give a good answer to your question. One is because of the following, which I'm not sure needs to be pointed out:

> Uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence.

So, yes, anywhere you have a assumption about pointwise convergence, you are 100% allowed to replace the assumption with uniform convergence. And the result will hold true. Example.

> *"Uniform" Monotone Convergence Theorem.* $f_n\to f$ uniformly and increases to $f$. Then $\int_a^b f_n \to \int_a^b f$.
>   Proof. Uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence. Now apply standard MCT.

The second is, under the assumption that $f_n,f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ are continuous, if you replace "pointwise and increasing" with "uniform", you end up with a true result. In fact, you end up with the statement of Question 1 ...so what do you mean its not enough? It *is* enough. But the above stream of comments indicates that I unfortunately don't know how to get a clearer statement out of you, so I hope this suffices.

PS Some of the usefulness of the monotone convergence theorem in measure theory is from how the assumptions of finiteness of the integrals are missing. This is not something you can appreciate at all, if you're only talking about continuous functions on $[a,b]$, and in this scenario the non-negativity is indeed not important (see the result above implied by Dini's Lemma).

Comment: This is in response to the second question. So basically uniform convergence will guarantee Monotone Convergence (provided we are on a bounded set) and the proof of it is exactly the same as in the Riemannan case? Also that the condition - point wise convergence (a.e.) and increasing in most measure theory books are the weakest hypothesis for the theorem to hold true.

Comment: @Hawk 1 Once you set up all the machinery, yes. 2 For continuous functions on $[a,b]$, you can actually just ask for pointwise convergence and $\|f_n\|_\infty<C$ for a constant $C$ that does not depend on $n$. This is a special case of dominated convergence theorem.  I don't think it's possible to get any weaker, for continuous functions (or even bounded functions)

Comment: Actually, the full strength of DCT is still more general even for continuous functions.  e.g. you can instead choose
$$ \tau_n(x) = n^\alpha \tilde T(nx)$$ for $\alpha<1$ and the integral $\int \tau_n \to \int T = 0$ indeed. This is predicted by the DCT, since  $\tau_n(x) $ is bounded above by a multiple of the integrable function $x^{-\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume throughout that you are talking about integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.

For your **first question**, you already give an excellent example for why point-wise convergence isn’t enough, which I’ll repeat here. We consider the case when $[a,b] = [0,1]$.

Let $f_n = 2n$ on $\left[\frac{1}{2n}, \frac 1n\right]$, and zero otherwise. Then, $f_n \to 0$ pointwise.

To see this, fix an $x > 0$, and let $N = \left\lceil \frac 1x \right\rceil + 1$. Then, for all $n \ge N$, $f_n (x) = 0$. If $x=0$, then $f_n (x) = 0$ for all $n$. This means that we do in fact have pointwise convergence to $f = 0$.

Now, we wish to check that the integral does not converge to zero, so we cannot interchange the limit and the integral for this choice of $\{f_n\}$. Since $f_n$ is a rectangle with base $\frac{1}{2n}$ and height $2n$, we have that $$ \int_0^1 f_n = 1 $$ for all $n$, so there is no way this integral converges to zero. In particular, as soon as $\varepsilon < 1$, there is no way we will have that $$ \int_0^1 \vert f_n - f\vert = \int_0^1 f_n < \int_0^1 \varepsilon = \varepsilon.$$

For your **second question**, if you are integrating over a finite interval, then uniform convergence is enough to guarantee that the conclusion of the monotone convergence theorem is true, for precisely the same reason it is true as in your first question.

If you are integrating over all of $\mathbb R$, then you will in general have $$ \left\lvert \int (f_n -f)\right\rvert \le \int \| f_n - f\|_\infty. $$ However, even if you could choose $n$ large enough so that $\| f_n - f \|_\infty < \varepsilon$, you could still have that $$ \int \| f_n -f \|_\infty = \infty ,$$ since $$ \int_\mathbb{R} \varepsilon = \infty $$ for every $\varepsilon >0$.

Comment: For your second statement that $\int \| f_n - f\|_\infty = \infty$ because $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \epsilon \to 0$, so does this mean I would be correct if we are integrating over an unbounded set? Say $[a,b]$

Comment: Do you mean a bounded set? Also $\int_\mathbb{R} \varepsilon \not\to 0$! $\int_\mathbb{R} \varepsilon$ **is infinite** for any $\varepsilon > 0$, so there is no way that it goes to zero even if you take $\varepsilon$ to zero.

Comment: Yes typo. I meant bounded set

Comment: So what is the resolution if bounded set?

Comment: When you are integrating over any subset of the real line with finite measure, then you can replace pointwise monotone convergence with uniform convergence. I say this in my answer in the paragraph that starts “[f]or your second question.”